# How can I use GSconnect cli for sending notification to phone?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, kde-connect

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/daemon.js -d $( ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/daemon.js -a) --share-text="hello"
```

I thought this is the alternative for ping-msg in kdeconnect cli but it keeps giving a JS Error:

Result:

```
(gsconnect:10749): Gjs-WARNING \*\*: 19:59:48.567: JS ERROR: TypeError: options.lookup_value(...) is null*
```

have anyone done this i couldn't get any example from googling